# structure tips that confusing

Tags: c, struct

i'm learning about structures in c and there are few tips confusing me 
so if we have a struct like this

```
struct Person{
char* name;
int age;
int weight;
int height;
};
```

now it is a compound datatype that i can deal with like other data types..
when i make pointer to this structure

```
struct Person pointer=malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

now c point to an address in the memory with the size if the struct my question is

A)is really c know that Person consists of 4 variable with names name,age,weight,height and make copy to this entity to new place which pointer points to ?

B)what is the difference  in this two syntax ?

```
struct Person *pointer=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
struct Person *pointer=malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

C)i'm not familiar with this function deceleration syntax so can any one clear up it to me (name of function is an pointer) ?

```
struct Person *Person_create(char* name, int age, int height, int   weight){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question A:**

> is really c know that Person consists of 4 variable with names name,age,weight,height and make copy to this entity to new place which pointer points to ?

**Answer:**

The answer to the first part of the question is 'yes' except I will rephrase it as *A C compiler knows...*

The second part of the question is not clear to me. I am not sure what you are asking.

**Question B:**

> what is the difference in this two syntax ?
>
> ```
> struct Person *pointer=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
> struct Person *pointer=malloc(sizeof(Person));
> ```

**Answer:**

If you use

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of your .c file, both are the same. If you don't that line, then

```
 struct Person *pointer=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

has the potential to hid a bug. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for further details.

**Question C:**

> i'm not familiar with this function deceleration syntax so can any one clear up it to me (name of function is an pointer) ?
>
> ```
> struct Person *Person_create(char* name, int age, int height, int   weight){...}
> ```

**Answer:**

The above syntax is correct if you want to allocate an object of type `struct Person` from heap using `malloc` family of functions and return a pointer to the allocated object.

You also have the option of return an object defined using stack memory.

```
 struct Person Person_create(char* name, int age, int height, int   weight){...}
```

Which one you choose depends entirely on you. You have to make sure that when you use heap memory for the object, you must remember to call `free()` on the pointer. Otherwise, your program will leak memory.

Comment: my second part of question A is 
      pointer->age=30;
after allocating process by malloc to the required memory how is c compiler act in the new allocated space to store variable called age with value 20 although age is an variable of struct person ?

Comment: `malloc` only returns you a set of bytes. It does not set any values on those bytes. You have to fill it up with the necessary data. `calloc`, on the other hand, returns you a set of bytes initialized to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A) No, `malloc()` returns an array of bytes which know nothing about what they are supposed to contain.  In particular, `pointer` points to an uninitialized `Person` which could contain anything until you initialize the fields (or `memset(pointer, 0, sizeof(Person))`).

B) The difference is that the one with the cast (`(Person*)`) is considered bad practice in C.  Use the shorter one, because it is shorter and doesn't hide potential errors.

C) `struct Person *Person_create` is not "the name of the function is a pointer," rather it is "a function which returns a pointer."  Some people would write it as `struct Person* Person_create` instead.

Comment: i got ur answer of my B question well but for A and C 
A) now malloc just returns array of bytes notintialised ..ok
when i make pointer->age=20; how c act in this case although in new allocated block there is no blocks called age and 
for C question we use this pointer to use the function so where is the function name and coule you provide me more about this syntax ?

Comment: Most things in C are just blocks of bytes, at runtime no type information is needed.  So using a  block of bytes as an integer is normal in C, you don't need to "convert" the block to an integer before storing a number in it.